# Run bash commands and simulate key strokes remotely

Tags: node.js, bash, terminal, sh, tty

In NodeJS, I can spawn a process and listen to its stdout using `spawn().stdout`. I'm trying to create an online terminal which will interact with this shell. I can't figure out how to send keystrokes to the shell process.

I've tried this:

`echo -e "ls\n" > /proc/{bash pid}/fd/0`

This doesn't really do anything other than output ls and a line break. And when I try to `tail -f /proc/{bash pid}/fd/0`, I can no longer even send keystrokes to the open `bash` terminal.

I'm really just messing around trying to understand how the `bash` process will interpret ENTER keys. I don't know if that is done through stdin or not since line breaks don't work.

Comment: Data written to a FD does not loop back to become available for reading on that FD. If this was the case, imagine how useless sockets would be.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can "remote control" an already started normal Bash session in any meaningful way. What you can do is start a new shell which reads from a [named pipe](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/NamedPipes); you can then write to that pipe to run commands:

```
$ cd "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ mkfifo pipe1
$ bash < pipe1 &
$ echo touch foo > pipe1
[1]+  Done                    bash < pipe1
$ ls
foo  pipe1
```

See [How to write several times to a fifo without having to reopen it?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/085) for more details.

Comment: How do I keep the bash process alive after piping commands to it?